# Bring up contact by Amatuer Radio callsign rather than name

Tags: search, advanced

We have a database of Amateur Radio operators. One field is their callsign.
What I would like to do to make editing events faster, is instead of polling by their name, to add callsign to advanced search.
Is this possible?
Thanks,
Steve

Comment: are you already using External ID for something else? if not it might be a good solution for CallSign

Comment: Or nickname?  You'd need to switch this on in settings

Comment: The field should be there in Advanced Search (assuming you checked "Is this field searchable" on the field settings) -- but it might be buried further down the page in the "Custom Fields" area.

Answer (score 1):

As Laryn notes, it should show up in the Custom Fields section of Advanced Search anyway providing the field is marked as searchable.

You can search by callsign in the Quicksearch box by going to `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Search Preferences` and ticking the callsign field in the Quicksearch options box.